# Linear interpolate where data is invalid

Tags: bash, awk, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I would like to linearly interpolate a single column based on previous and next know values only where data is equal to "---".

Data example:

```
0
---
---
---
10
---
20
22
15
---
---
---
-15
```

Wanted output:

```
0
2.5
5
7.5
10
15
20
22
15
7.5
0
-7.5
-15
```

I have seen codes that can interpolate based on first column such as date, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792172/using-awk-to-interpolate-data-column-based-in-a-data-file-with-date-and-time). And other codes that would do it for step size, like [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/213367-computing-linearly-interpolated-values-using-awk.html) but they won't work for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use another language than bash. Python has [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) ([example2](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-interpolate-set-of-points.html)), [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) modules, all of which implement linear interpolation and would likely be easier to deal with than bash.

Comment: Thanks @jeremysprofile but I don't know any python. I just started scripting using bash and awk and still trying to understand the basics of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!/---/ {n=c; while(c&&c--) print v+(n-c)*($1-v)/(n+1); v=$1; print } 
        /---/ {c++}' file

0
2.5
5
7.5
10
15
20
22
15
7.5
0
-7.5
-15
```